# A Problem about Quadratic Forms and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of my linear algebra lectures, the lecturer gave a theorem:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a quadratic form, with matrix $A$. Then $f$ is positive definite if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.

Here is her proof of $(\Rightarrow)$:

She tried to prove the contrapositive of $(\Rightarrow)$. Suppose one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is not positive, since $A$ is symmetric, then $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable, i.e., $\exists$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ=D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of which the diagonal entries are eigenvalues of $A$, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$. By the Principal Axes Theorem, 
$$
f({\bf{x}})={\bf{x}}^TA{\bf{x}}=(Q{\bf{y}})^TA(Q{\bf{y}})={\bf{y}}^TD{\bf{y}}=\lambda_1y_1^2+\lambda_2y_2^2+\cdots+\lambda_ny_n^2, 
$$
where 
$$
{\bf{y}}=(y_1y_2\dots y_n)^T=Q^T{\bf{x}}=Q^T(x_1x_2\dots x_n)^T.
$$
Let ${\bf{y}}={\bf{e}}_i=(00\dots010\dots0)^T$, a unit vector of which the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate is $1$. Then ${\bf{x}}=Q{\bf{y}}$ and we get 
$$
f({\bf{x}})=\lambda_i\leqslant0. 
$$
Then $f$ is not positive definite.

Is this proof right? Could somebody tell me if her proof is appropriate? The proof of contrapositive should be without any examples I suppose?

Comment: I don't like very much the use of the contrapositive argument here, the direct proof is perfectly viable and gives a lot more information. (Anyway, the proof is OK)

Comment: @rschwieb: Is it? But the problem is that if that ${\bf{y}}$ always exists for all $f$?

Comment: @TeddyFrei Hang on, I'm changing my mind about what's here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, this is not a proof by contradiction. It is a proof of the *contrapositive.*

The form of the argument is "If not $B$ implies not $A$." Since this is logically equivalent to "If $A$ then $B$", that has been proven also.

It could be rewritten as an argument by contradiction. One would say "Suppose all eigenvalues are positive but also $x^\top Qx\leq 0$ for some $x$." Then one can rewrite $x$ as a linear combination of orthogonal eigenvectors and show that one of the eigenvalues is nonpositive, causing a contradiction.

*Edit:* The poster has since rewritten the question and made this part useless.

---

OK, let me try to address what you're saying about "examples."  The argument is of the form "If **for all** eigenvalues of $Q$...*something happens*, then **for all** vectors, *something else happens*." The proof by contrapositive would then go this way:

1. OK, assume there *is* a vector such that *something else* doesn't happen.
2. (*insert valid steps of reasoning*)
3. Aha, I produced an eigenvalue for which the first *something* doesn't happen.

You can see the negations of the original universal quantifiers become *existential quantifiers* in the negation. 
That is, the contrapositive of "$\forall \lambda(\phi(\lambda))\implies \forall x(\psi (x))$" turns into

$\exists x(\neg\psi(x))\implies \exists \lambda(\neg\phi(\lambda))$

My guess is that you are saying that using these existential quantifiers to assert the existence of "an example" makes you uncomfortable. But it shouldn't... this is a perfectly natural use of logic :)

Comment: Yes.. sorry that was my fault in the previous comment. But from 'not $B$' to 'not $A$', it should be prove from the general hypothesis 'at least one of eigenvalues of $A$ is not positive' to '$f$ is not positive definite' without using any examples...

Comment: @TeddyFrei Hmm... By "without using any examples" what do you mean? You mean nobody can talk about vectors?

Comment: I mean should she use ${\bf{y}}={\bf{e}}_i$ as an example to show that $f$ is not positive definite?

Comment: @TeddyFrei OK, take a look now

Comment: Ok, then is it possible for ${\bf{y}}$ to take ${\bf{e}}_i$ for all $f$? i.e., is the use of existence quantifier correct?

Comment: @TeddyFrei I do not see any problem in the argument you originally gave. The existence of a nonpositive eigenvalue made a diagonal matrix with a nonpositive diagonal element, and then there is a realization that if this is the case, then there is an obvious candidate for a vector whose length is nonpositive.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is OK, but to be honest, I would prove the direct statement rather than the contrapositive. Actually, with no extra effort that proof shows that 
$$\tag{1}
\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2\le f(x)\le \lambda_{\mathrm{max}}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2,\quad \forall x=(x_1\ldots x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Here $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}$ are, respectively, the minimum and maximum eigenvalue of $A$. So if $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}>0$, then $f$ is positive definite. Moreover, the inequalities are *sharp*, meaning that there exist vectors $x_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $x_{\mathrm{max}}$ such that 
$$\tag{2}
\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2=f(x_{\mathrm{min}})
$$
and
$$\tag{3}
f(x_{\mathrm{max}})=\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2,
$$
precisely, one must take eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}$ respectively. Therefore, if $f$ is positive definite, then $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}>0$, because the right hand side in (2) is positive by assumption.

Comment: Should (1) be written as $\lambda_{\min}\sum y_j^2\leqslant f({\bf{x}})\leqslant\lambda_{\max}\sum y_j^2$? I got quite confused...

Comment: Yes, that's OK too. In fact it is exactly the same formula. Remember that $y$ and $x$ differ by an orthogonal matrix: $x=Qy$. So $\sum x_j^2= x^Tx=y^TQ^TQy=\ldots$

Comment: Ah yes truly the direct one makes much more sense and is more comfortable than the contrapositive.. Thanks a lot bro